# React Redux architecture suggestion

Tags: reactjs, redux

Confussed between which is best to use react class state or redux state for  `onChange` operation of the form elements.

I have a form for entering,displaying user details, I am using `react-redux` architecture, on-change or on-load I am populating the data from the api to the respective text boxes using the class state/localstate, when the user inputs any data I am using the `setState` . I came to know that there is another way to do it by dispatching an action and storing the data in the `redux` state instead of local state,so please suggest me which is the standard way to do it, as some prefer not to use local state.

Comment: Redux is great to share data in your all app, and make data persistant in case you want to save/restore your all app state by having a single tree to store. If you don't need any of those two i would suggest to use local state instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generaly as @sebastienbarbier suggested. If you don't need to share your state between different parts of application, the react state is usually better.

I am using the react state for handling onChange for controlled components (typically text inputs). And a redux action is created (and store updated) once when I submit a form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use formik library for handling your forms.

Formik use state by itself for handling state.

https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/